# How to replace decltype(f()) with std::invoke_result_t, where f is a lambda with non-type template parameter?

Tags: c++, c++20, type-traits

How to replace the following with `std::invoke_result_t`?

```
decltype(f.template operator()<0>())
```

Here's more context:

```
template <size_t I, typename Functor>
consteval void apply(Functor&& f)
{
    using ResultType = decltype(f.template operator()<0>())>);
    // ... More stuff ...
    f.template operator()<I>());
}

void test() {
   apply<5>([]<auto I>() {
   });
}
```

Comment: Why? What's wrong with the `decltype`?

Comment: @Barry: it doesn't compile with MSVC 19.29 (VS 2019) and clang prior to version 14.

Comment: [Here is it compiling on clang 10](https://godbolt.org/z/7n5o8faE4) (once I fix the typos). [And 19.22](https://godbolt.org/z/oqP67Wdaz), which is the first version that supports declaring lambdas like that. Maybe that's the real issue?

Comment: @Barry: odd, here's the actual code and it doesn't compile: https://godbolt.org/z/7cG9xn6Pq

Comment: @VioletGiraffe This might make for a good question on its own, or maybe it could replace this one. Here is a reduced test case: https://godbolt.org/z/sv5163aMM. I could provide an answer explaining what the issue is. (For MSVC it is simply a bug that I don't think you can solve by replacing the decltype. Old Clang versions reject correctly due to following old standard wording faithfully. It has since been corrected and Clang 14, following the new wording, should compile the decltype version just fine.)

Comment: If you want to stick with fixing the decltype issue in older Clang versions, I would also suggest adding `consteval` to the lambda (which is the cause of the problems) in the question and I would suggest you ask for a general work around instead since `std::invoke_result` can probably not be used.

Comment: @user17732522: that's very interesting, thank you. Turns out that with clang 12 the problem is with `decltype` (since the proposed answer works), and with MSVC it's something else - I'll have to forego VS 2019 support. What was the changed standard wording about, is it a C++20 change? Also, I didn't realize `invoke_result` requires a function pointer and `consteval ` functions do not allow taking their pointer.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe It is a bit more complicated whether or not taking the address of a `consteval` function is allowed. The relevant change is the wording change in https://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1937r2.html. As I mentioned, I could write a proper answer for a matching question.

Comment: @user17732522: I would be happy to post the question and learn your answer, but I don't quite understand what that question should be. Why did you say that `invoke_result` will not solve my underlying problem and will actually make it worse? Turned out that `invoke_result` works since Clang 12, not since 14.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe The question is whether or not there is a `consteval` on the lambda as well. If there isn't, then both `decltype(f.template operator()<0>())>)` and the solution in the answer with `invoke_result` will work fine. If there is, neither will work in Clang 12, but will in Clang 14. Without the `consteval` the question seems pointless since `decltype(...)` also works. But there is now a direct answer taking the question at face value anyway, so I wouldn't change it anymore. If you are still interested in the variant with `consteval` as in your comments you could post another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need `decltype`, because `invoke_result_t` requires the type of the method followed by the type of the class.  But here you go:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <type_traits>

template <size_t I, typename Functor>
consteval auto apply(Functor&& f)
{
    // using ResultType = decltype(f.template operator()<0>());
    using ResultType = std::invoke_result_t<
        decltype(&std::remove_cvref_t<Functor>::template operator()<0>),
        Functor>;
        // ... More stuff ...
    return ResultType(f.template operator()<I>());
}

void
test()
{
    apply<5>([]<auto I>() {
        });
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer to the question as it was posted, but unfortunately that will not resolve the asker's underlying problem discussed in the comments. (In fact making it worse instead.)

Comment: @user3188445 You declared `apply()` as having a return type of `void`, so the `return` statement will fail to compile if the `Functor`'s `operator()` returns anything other than `void`. Also, if `ResultType` is supposed to be the type that the `Functor`'s `operator()` returns, then why type-cast the result of calling the `operator()` at all? Just change `apply()`'s return type to `auto`, and get rid of `ReturnType` in the `return` statement: `template <size_t I, typename Functor>
consteval auto apply(Functor&& f) { ... return f.template operator()<I>(); }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau The compiler was giving me a warning for declaring a typedef (`ResultType`) that I didn't use, so I wrapped the return type just to use it.  I just changed it to return `auto`.  Obviously if the OP wants this typedef, the real code is going to look different, so can be adapted.  I was just trying to show what proper usage of `std::invoke_result_t` looks like, mostly so the OP sees it probably doesn't solve his/her problem.

Comment: @user3188445, thank you! This kind of `invoke_result` usage is not covered by any example on cppreference, so I had no idea this is how you do this. Good to know. So the syntax for member functions is `<function_pointer, this, explicit arguments...>` ?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe This is described on the page for [invoke](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke), where "if f is a pointer to member function... INVOKE(f, t1, ...) is equivalent to (f.*t1)(...)".